# AZURE vm, not confugured

Tags: azure, configuration, dns, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine

can anyone help with some azure vm issues. I wished to connect a domain server VM and a ordinary server VM and use active directory synchronization. But every time I deploy new VM from azure portal, it always have the DNS name status as not configured. I really don't understand why. I set the DNS server with the private IPs of the VMs on the vNet. Thanks for replies and advise. [VM DNS name not configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey6d5.jpg)

Comment: Hi Maria,

if your new VM is going to be connected to an AD domain and uses private IPs you would not need to configure DNS name for that VM.

DNS name not configured appears if there is no public IP address associated with your vm. If you associate a public IP address to access VM over internet it will allow you to set a dns name.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment stated, the DNS name for that VM is actually associated with the public IP attached to that VM. You can follow [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/create-fqdn#create-a-fqdn) to create FQDN for an Azure VM.

If you want to join the Azure VM to your local domain, you can follow [this link](https://4sysops.com/archives/join-an-azure-vm-to-an-on-prem-active-directory/):

The main steps are as follows:

- Establish cross-site connectivity using Azure site-to-site VPN connections
- Configure a custom DNS server
- Provision a VM with a custom DNS server
- Join the Azure VM to the on-premises Active Directory domain

If you intend to join a Windows Server virtual machine to an Azure Active Directory Domain Services managed domain, read this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm).